# 3000+ page doesn't contain any image then and Ahref showing error for not using Open graph tag

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have angular and node.js based custom website

**Problem **

I am facing an issue While auditing my website in the Ahref I got the OG(Open Graph) tag missing wranning.

I can add but problem is that I have 3000+ same layout design of pages where no image are used on whole webpage.

- Now, If I use **og:image** tag then no image can be link in that becuse there is no images on webpage.
- Another point is that, if I use custom image then it is not possible for me to create and upload custom images for each pages. Also this will increase server load...

**Check Page layout:** https://www.cityxrayclinic.com/book-a-test/cbc-complete-blood-counts

Please suggest me something to get rid of this problem..

It is possible without og:image I can go with other tags.. I think it is not good practice